# java: How Can I click all options in dropdown after selecting dropdown again

Tags: java, select, drop-down-menu

I'm working on a dropdown which have 4 options and I need to click each option everytime I expand (or click) on the dropdown menu. I have written logic which clicks on particular element for first time, but when I expands the dropdown, the code is failing to click any other option in the dropdown. Please let me know where I'm doing mistake.

Code -

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);     

    // gets all the options in the dropdown.
    List<WebElement> select = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@class='select2-results__option']"));
    System.out.println(select.size());
    for (int i=0; i<select.size();i++) {
        select.get(i).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        // drodpdown element
        List<WebElement> ele = driver.findElements(By.xpath(GetPropertValue("dropdownvalue")));
        // expands the dropdown again.
        ele.get(1).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        select.get(i).click();
    }

} catch (Exception e ){
    Assert.fail("unable to click option from services");
}
```

dropdown code snippet -

```html
<ul class="select2-results__options ps-container ps-theme-default" role="tree" id="select2-j_idt2339-results" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false" data-ps-id="fcad5f76-4b37-a689-7d7c-d975c236d339">

<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-j_idt2339-result-x9ct-022" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Issue License</li>

<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-j_idt2339-result-wuzg-023" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Issue License from Old License</li>

<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-j_idt2339-result-b9ni-024" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Replace License</li>

<li class="select2-results__option" id="select2-j_idt2339-result-zj1d-025" role="treeitem" aria-selected="false">Renew License</li>

<div class="ps-scrollbar-x-rail" style="left: 0px; bottom: 3px;">
    <div class="ps-scrollbar-x" tabindex="0" style="left: 0px; width: 0px;"></div>
</div>

<div class="ps-scrollbar-y-rail" style="top: 0px; right: 3px;">
    <div class="ps-scrollbar-y" tabindex="0" style="top: 0px; height: 0px;"></div>
</div>

</ul>​
```

I have added the below code but it is failing to click the dropdown.

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class=' form-field ']/span[1]/span[1]/span"));

    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@role='tree']/li"));
System.out.println(list.size());
 Thread.sleep(5000);
    for(int i=1;i<list.size();i++) {
         Thread.sleep(5000);
       dropdown.click();
       Thread.sleep(3000);
        list.get(i).click();
   Thread.sleep(5000);

        System.out.println("Selected : " +list.get(i).getText());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code:

```
WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@id='select2-j_idt2339-results']"));
    List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='select2-j_idt2339-results']/li"));
    for(int i=1;i<options.size();i++) {
         dropdown.click();
         Thread.sleep(3000);
        options.get(i).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        System.out.println("Selected : " +options.get(i).getText());
    }
```

Another way to select the dropdown options (You can also use selectbyvisibletext or selectbyvalue instead of selectbyindex):

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("<Xpath of Dropdown>")));
for(int i=0;i<=dropdown.getOptions().size();i++) {
    dropdown.selectByIndex(i);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    }
```

Comment: I tried above mentioned code but not able to click dropdown and it is failing there.

Comment: Failing where? its not able to find the dropdown element?? What error are your getting?

Comment: failing to click the dropdown element. it says unable to find element.

Comment: am still seeing same issue. able to select option from dropdown for first time, but not able to select second time.

Comment: ok.. can you tell me the output of options.size()? is it returning 5?

Comment: its returning 4 .. what I did is , after clicking one option, expanded the dropdown at that time instead of clicking, jumping to Exception block

Comment: Is it possible to paste the error that you are getting here?

Comment: as I have embedded into Try/Catch, it is printing me the message in catch block . - Assert.fail("unable to click option from services");

Comment: The above code is working fine for me. First u need to click on the dropdown and then click on the options. If you want to select the options again, u have to click on the dropdown again and select the options. Add sleep methods to wait for the element to appear. You can add wait until conditions also to wait for an element.

Comment: strange that it is not working for me! okay let me try adding the timeout. thanks! will get back in case of any queries

Comment: ok. Can you add throws InterruptedException and try> Its same as try/catch.. but u can try once. Don't try to add the sleep methods.

Comment: sure.. If its still not working, pls post your code again.. will check once

Comment: Yeah, sure. I'll do that.

Comment: I have tried code which I have added in my edit post. but still unable to click the dropdown menu

Comment: Can you try this code:  Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("<Xpath of Dropdown>")));
for(int i=0;i<=dropdown.getOptions().size();i++) {
 dropdown.selectByIndex(i);
 Thread.sleep(3000);
 }